# Windows 7 File Manager: Explorer, Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

How to make my user name the **default** in the explorer Navigation Pane

Comment: By your name do you mean your home directory? (C:\Users\mylogin)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make it always the default, but you can create a shortcut to that folder on your desktop or menu.